# Pixel 2 (Android 10) disconnecting on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-10.0, disconnect

Not sure if this is the right place to ask. I have seen other similar questions, but none that appear directly applicable.

Using Android Studio for development, two USB connected target devices - Nexus 7 2013 (OS 6) and Pixel 2 (OS 10, was 9).

Debugging, apk loading etc worked absolutely fine until the day the Pixel was upgraded to OS 10 (still is 100% fine on the Nexus 7). Now the Pixel randomly keeps disconnecting. In the ADB devices dialog it will show up as a string of hex digits instead of 'Pixel 2 ...', or occasionally, not at all.

Unplugging it and plugging in again will fix it, but a few minutes, or sometimes 10s of minutes later, it'll do it again.

I am sure it is not physical as (a) have tried different cables / cleaning sockets to no effect and (b) it was 100% OK until the day I installed OS 10. Too coincidental.

I notice that sometimes actions on the device can precipitate it, eg if an email suddenly arrives - but not always.

Looks to me that something times out occasionally?

Comment: You should probably mention your PC's OS along with if you connecting via USB2 or USB3 ports.

Comment: Windows 10, USB 2.

Comment: Same happening here, OS 10, USB 2, W 10.